# How do I check if there are duplicate numbers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, duplicates

I have to find out if there are duplicate numbers in an array, and if there is a duplicate found I need to -5 points. Here is my code so far:

```
for (int k = 0; k < arrNums2.length; k++) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrNums2.length; i++) 
    {
        if (arrNums2[k] == arrNumsCompare[i])
        {             
            points = points - 5;            
            for (int j = 0; j < arrNums2.length; j++)
            {
                if (arrNums2[k] == arrNums2[j])
                {
                    arrNums2[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: Sort this array, then iterate over it. If neighbours are equal, you've got a duplicate.

Comment: @PradeepSimha - I really doubt if `Set` can be used in this case. There is something related to points to be done, in case a duplicate is found. Set won't even let you know that it found a duplicate

Comment: That's **NOT A DUPLICATE**, he has a problem, and it needs to be solved. I don't see it there. If he gets a ready solution, for a problem that's not like his problem, he'll not learn anything and won't learn from his mistakes.

Comment: Why are you doing this `arrNums2[j]=0;` ? is it a requirement or part of your logic?

Comment: Part of my logic , i have changed it to -1 now though , but it still wont work because then it will end up finding -1's that are =

Comment: yes, Find my answer below and Must read the note carefully.

Comment: @akluth - How do you call this a **duplicate** of Compare elements in an array for duplicates? Only the titles are similar. Read through the question and answers.

Comment: Note : If your array is an array of Integer instead of int, then `if(arrNums2[k]==arrNums2[j])` might not work. In this case, use `equals` instead.

Comment: Sure you can use a set, then just do `points -= (listSize - setSize)*5`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest this one line solution :

```
Integer[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1};

return 5 * (new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(numbers)).size() - numbers.length);
```

I add all the elements to a Set, which by definition refuses duplicates. Then I compare the size of the set to the length of the array and multiply the result by 5.

Comment: +1, but you should use a HashSet instead for speed

Comment: +1 Most elegant and simple answer. With good explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

You can work on this pseudo code:

```
int nDuplicates = 0;
arrNums2 = arrNums2.Sort(); // Sort the array in ascending or descending order. 

for(int i =1; i<arrNums2.size(); ++i)
{ 
 if(arrNums2[i-1] == arrNums2[i])
 {
  nDuplicates++;
 }
}
Point -= nDuplicates*5;
```

**Edit:** If the input 5,5,5,5 has to be considered as a single duplication then use the following snippet.

```
    int nDuplicates = 0;
    arrNums2 = arrNums2.Sort(); // Sort the array in ascending or descending order. 
    int DuplicateNumber = 0;
       for(int i =1; i<arrNums2.size(); ++i)
        { 
         if(arrNums2[i-1] == arrNums2[i])
         {
          if(DuplicateNumber != arrNums2[i])
          {
           nDuplicates++;
           DuplicateNumber = arrNums2[i];
          }
         }
        }
     Point -= nDuplicates*5;
```

Comment: Ohk i seem to have it working from here , but the only problem where it sitll does not work is if user enters for example : 5,5,5,5,5

Comment: What is the problem? It would be considered as 3 duplicates of 5. Or you want it as a single duplicate?

Comment: @JoshBoiskin - I have edited my answer to accommodate the second possibility of considering 5,5,5,5 as a single duplication.

Answer (score 0):

This loops seems to go for ever until negative value limit reaches.
It seems you have made the temp array `arrNumsCompare` to implement logic.
Here you Go:

```
   for (int k=0; k < arrNums2.length; k++) 
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < arrNums2.length; i++) 
       {
         if(i == k)
         {
           i++;
         } 
         if(arrNums2[k]==arrNums2[i])
         {             
            points = points -5;
            break;
         }
       }
     }
```

**NOTE:** If a value is present 3 times the deduction would be 10 and so on. If you want to deduct it once, you would need to work further.Ask me if you could not do that.

**Hint:** you would need to maintain another array of number already marked duplicate and add another  check to skip  :)

Comment: Yeah , ohk i will work on that , because if a duplicate is found it must not be counted again

Comment: If a value exists 4 times, you need to deduct 5 points only?

Comment: Yes ,is it better to skip that index ? maybe by setting it to say -1 , and then only check slots if the are not = -1 ?

Comment: Do not alter your array. i am adding to my answer above. wait a couple of minutes.

Comment: Another question about your code ? , what is the reason you check to see if i =k and then i++? should'nt you be checking the actual array not the slot number?

Comment: because when you will parse the array you will find the number itself arr[2] equals arr[2], right? if i=2 and k =2 :).

Comment: Still doesnt make sense to me .. xD , sorry

Comment: arr ={5,6,7} ; i=1 and k=1 then `arr[i] == arr[k]` is true, that is, 6==6. because arr[1] = 6. got it? Now mark my comments and answer useful :)

Comment: ahhh , i am going to try start over again , i have gotten so lost right now xD

Comment: See my second answer as well, dry run the code to understand it. dry run means to execute on paper using pen:)

Answer (score 0):

To find duplicates in one iteration over the original array without prior sorting you can use a HashMap to store each of the entries and increment count every time you find it again.
This way you can stop processing as soon as you find the first duplicate or continue to find all...

**Edit:**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

```
Hashmap entries  = new Hashmap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int k = 0; k < arrNums2.length; k++) {
       if (!entries.containsKey(arrNums2[k])) {
         entries.put(arrNums2[k], 1);
       } else {
         // You already found the duplicate, so you can do whatever you like 
         Integer count = entries.get(arrNums2[k]);
         count = count + 1;
         entries.put(arrNums2[k], count);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Could u give me an example of this HashMap?

Answer (score 0):

**Second Version to deduct points once for as many duplicates**

Array must contain only positive numbers for this solution.

```
for (int k=0; k < arrNums2.length; k++) 
     {
       if(arrNums2[k] == -1)
       {
         continue;
       }
       Boolean found = fasle;
       for (int i = k+1; i < arrNums2.length; i++) 
       {             
         if(arrNums2[k]==arrNums2[i])
         {  
            if(found == false)
            {            
               points = points -5;
               found = true;           
            }
            arrNums2[i] = -1;
         }
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the set {1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9} With points stating at 100 the following code will reduce the points by 10. As if only 2 duplicates exist. hope this helps.

```
private int[] numbers;
private Set<Integer> previousDuplicates = new HashSet<Integer>();
private int points;


public void reducePointsForDuplicates(){
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         reducePointsIfDuplicate(i, numbers[i]);
    }
}

private void reducePointsIfDuplicate(int position, int number){
    for (int i = position + 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(number == numbers[i]){ 
            reducePointsForNewDuplicate(number);
        }
    }
}

private void reducePointsForNewDuplicate(int number){
    if (!previousDuplicates.contains(number)){
        points = points - 5;
    }
    previousDuplicates.add(number);
}



public int[] getNumbers() {
    return numbers;
}

public void setNumbers(int[] numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setPoints(int points) {
    this.points = points;
}
```

Comment: It will work on sorted array only.

Comment: I tested it. It works whether the array is sorted or not.

Comment: Got it, we don't need to check before the position as we have tested it already.

Comment: make it `for (int i = position+1` and remove the check `position != i &&` from `if(position != i && number == numbers[i])`

Comment: Have edited the code as suggested, it does make it a little easier to read and of course works just the same.